# How can I quickly write a fixed point matrix to a file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, printf

I have a piece of code in matlab to write a fixed point matrix to a text file. One element of the matrix B must in one line of the text. Each line of the 'binary.txt' file will contain one element of B. Let r1,r2,...,r100 be the rows of matrix B. Suppose that the (i,j)th element of B is x and its binary respresentation be 1101110111011110. Then in the (i*N + j)th line of 'binary.txt', the string 1101110111011110 must be written. Basically stack the rows of B into a long row vector, then transpose the resultant row vector (into a column vector) and write that column vector into a file.

```
M = 100,N = 10000;
A = rand(M,N);
B = fi(A,1,16,15);
fid = fopen('binary.txt','w');
for i = 1:M
    for j = 1:N
        cval = B(i,j);
        fprintf(fid,'%s\n',cval.bin); % write binary value to the file.
    end    
end
fclose(fid);
```

The file write portion of the code is slow. How can I make the file writing fast?

Comment: What is `cval.bin`? I don't recognize the syntax.

Comment: @rayryeng cval.bin is the binary string corresponding to the 16 bit fixed point representation.

Comment: So is it my understanding that it's a string of 16 characters that contains `'0'` and `'1'`?

Comment: @rayryeng. Yes the same.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this problem correctly, `B` is a matrix of structures where each structure has a field called `bin` which contains a 16 character string of 0s and 1s.  You are trying to write each string in this structure as a separate line in the output file.

You can take all of the strings and form them into a comma-separated list and write all of the strings simultaneously with one string per line.

Do this instead:

```
% // Your code
M = 100,N = 10000;
A = rand(M,N);
B = fi(A,1,16,15);
fid = fopen('binary.txt','w');

%// New code
B = B.';
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', B.bin);
fclose(fid);
```

Take note that I had to **transpose** the matrix `B` before writing all of the strings simultaneously.  The reason why is because when we collect all of the strings into a comma-separated list, this is done in **column-major** order.  Your code is writing the strings in **row-major** order, and so if you want to process things in row-major order, you need to transpose the matrix before you start working on the data.

## Example

```
clear B
B(1,1) = struct('bin', char(48 + randi(2, 1, 16) - 1));
B(1,2) = struct('bin', char(48 + randi(2, 1, 16) - 1));
B(2,1) = struct('bin', char(48 + randi(2, 1, 16) - 1));
B(2,2) = struct('bin', char(48 + randi(2, 1, 16) - 1));
fid = fopen('binary.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', B.bin);
fclose(fid);
```

I get this for the text file:

```
1100011111111010
0101110110010110
1100001101110000
1100011110000101
```

Comment: I tested your code. But it is giving a single line in the 'binary.txt' file. I have updated my question also.

Comment: @Vinod I tested this code on my own and it writes each string as a separate line.  Your code output is not reproducible because we don't have access to `fi`.  Please put your code for this function up on your question so we can run your code.

Comment: @Vinod - I've added in a reproducible example.  I get it as one entry per line.

Comment: @rayreng Your structure example is working correctly. But I need the fixed point matrix to be written to file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80351/discussion-between-vinod-and-rayryeng).